# accepts_nested_attributes_for with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

Is there any way to halt saving of child before parent.

I am using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with polymorphic association.

I used multiple options `validates_presence_of :parent_id` , `validates_assoicated :parent` but none are working.

For example, I do have a class

```
Class Person
  include HasPhoneNumbers
  ..
end


module HasPhoneNumbers
 def self.included(kclass)
   kclass.has_many :phone_numbers, :as => :callable, :dependent => kclass == Person ? :destroy : :nullify
 end
 klass.accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_numbers, :reject_if => lambda {|pn| pn.keys.any?{|k| k.to_sym != :id && pn[k].blank?} }
end


class PhoneNumber
  belongs_to :callable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

So while saving person due to validation in person object, it was not saving. However,  child(phone_number) was saving. So I need to restrict it to not save child(phone_number) before parent(person) saves.

I did try multiple options using `validates_presence_of` and `validates_associated`, but none are working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
@person = Person.new(params[:person])
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  person.save!
end
```

Wrapping your saves within a transaction should roll back the phone number save if the person fails validation.

Reference: [ActiveRecord Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the input..I already embed the code within transaction but somehow it is not rolling back..is there any way we can resolve this issue.